# How do I add variables together to create a brand new variable in MatLab

Tags: matlab, variables

I'm using MatLab for a uni assignment.

I have the following variables:

```
benchpress1=shimmer1(1:512,:);
benchpress2=shimmer1(2304:2815,:);
benchpress3=shimmer1(4608:5119,:);
benchpress4=shimmer1(6912:7423,:);
```

And I need to now add them together to create the new variable "benchpress"

I've used this line of code to add the variables to give me the new total

```
benchpress = benchpress1 + benchpress2 + benchpress3 + benchpress4;
```

But it doesn't recognise that I've added them! I need to plot the new variable against the "Time"

But when I do, I get the following error message:

```
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in week5 (line 24)
plot(time, benchpress);
```

And it shows that my total variable hasn't changed in length.

Just wondering if anyone knows what the problem might be. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to concatenate the `benchpress`'s if you want 1 columns (ie `time` is 2048 long)

```
benchpress = [benchpress1; benchpress2; benchpress3; benchpress4];
```

But if `time` is 512 long

```
benchpress = [benchpress1, benchpress2, benchpress3, benchpress4];
```

Comment: Ok so firstly thank you for answering.. I do want my time to be 2048 but I've tried both those lines of code and still neither of them work. I'm still getting that same error as before... any ideas?

Comment: What is `size(time)`?